# Как отправить данные формы из балуна в БД с помощью templateLayoutFactory

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии балуна не срабатывал метод build, но если нажать на кнопку внутри балуна методы отрабатывали?
Цель: отправлять в БД данные формы.
Проблема: когда балун открывается, отправляет запрос на бэк с пустыми полями формы. Все происходит без нажатия кнопки, на которую повесил 'click'.
Код здесь: https://jsbin.com/tagojutuse/edit?js

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Посмотрите ещё раз пример из песочницы, там кнопка отрабатывает корректно: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout Если у вас иная ситуация - представьте минимальный пример на https://jsbin.com/ или в другой песочнице.

Comment: Хорошо, посмотрю, с утра, но думаю, что там все порядке и сравнивал не раз, а методы запускает функция, которая передает адрес или создает метку